# deleting/updating spark dataframe rows based on values in other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have 2 data frames and I join these 2 based on whether a string in the one of the columns is contained in a message column in another dataframe.

Example DFs:

DF1

| Id | Application | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | facebook | could not connect to facebook. java.lang.NullPointerException |
| 2 | google | Connection to the application could not established .Description[stepupRequestId:may not be null ] |
| 3 | homedepot | PorcupineCourier -Execution of Connection to the application could not established. java.lang.NullPointerException |

DF2

| Event_Id | Token | SortOrder | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | java.lang.NullPointerException | 25 | yes |
| 20 | PorcupineCourier -Execution of | 9 | no |
| 30 | stepupRequestId:may not be null | 1 | no |

If I do a left join of these 2 dataframes like below

val result1 = df1.join(df2, $"Message.contains($"Token"), left)

output DF looks like this

| Id | Application | Message | Event_Id | Token | SortOrder | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | facebook | could not connect to facebook. java.lang.NullPointerException | 10 | java.lang.NullPointerException | 25 | yes |
| 2 | google | Connection to the application could not established .Description[stepupRequestId:may not be null ] | 30 | stepupRequestId:may not be null | 1 | no |
| 3 | homedepot | PorcupineCourier -Execution of Connection to the application could not established. java.lang.NullPointerException | 20 | PorcupineCourier -Execution of | 9 | no |
| 3 | homedepot | PorcupineCourier -Execution of Connection to the application could not established. java.lang.NullPointerException | 10 | java.lang.NullPointerException | 25 | yes |

Message = "PorcupineCourier -Execution of Connection to the application could not established. java.lang.NullPointerException" in DF1 has multiple tokens and i end up having 2 matches for the same message in my output.

But, i would like to use SortOrder Column in DF2 to get the right match and drop the duplicate row.I would like to get Event_Id with lowest SortOrder in case of multiple token matches, hence in the above output Event_Id = 20 has the lowest SortOrder, my output should have only 3 rows as below

Expected Output :

| Id | Application | Message | Event_Id | Token | SortOrder | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | facebook | could not connect to facebook. java.lang.NullPointerException | 10 | java.lang.NullPointerException | 25 | yes |
| 2 | google | Connection to the application could not established .Description[stepupRequestId:may not be null ] | 30 | stepupRequestId:may not be null | 1 | no |
| 3 | homedepot | PorcupineCourier -Execution of Connection to the application could not established. java.lang.NullPointerException | 20 | PorcupineCourier -Execution of | 9 | no |

also, if the message matches multiple tokens and both have the same SortOrder, i would like to get the row which defaults to the lowest Event_Id value

I am stuck and would appreciate any help in getting the logic right

Answer (score 1):

To drop the duplicate.  This is a fairly standard pattern to drop duplicate rows.

```scala
result1.withColumn("rn", row_number over Window.partitionBy('Id).orderBy('SortOrder, 'Event_Id)).where('rn === 1)
```

We put SortOrder as first ranking criteria, then Event_id.  It's by nature ascending order. If you have nulls, you may want to do `.asc_nulls_last` on the sort column

I implemented a more internally native version of it here: https://github.com/kanielc/jarvis-utils/blob/d95442ffad1d61d9269e87228e0911508784655f/src/main/scala/com/jarvis/utils/DatasetFunctions.scala#L27

but the version above will work just as well.